# Azure Media Services - How to increase ingestion speed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I am using Azure Media Service to allow users of a social site to upload video.  Here is the problem, I am noticing that it is taking up to around 30 minutes for each video to process.  Is there a way, through the admin., to limit the amount of time this takes?  The largest file so far is around 12 mb.

Comment: You can scale to use another kind of machine (A1, A2... A5) or multiple machines to encode the file.

Comment: Where is this in the admin. console on windowsazure portal?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-portal-encoding-units/

Answer (score 1):

Look into using Reserved Units - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/10/high-speed-encoding-with-azure-media-services/ .